# Make a timer with ranking in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, milliseconds

I want a ranking in my app where you can see who has the fastest lap.
I try to convert the time into milliseconds, but it didn't work well.

This is my code at the moment.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize watch,start,reset;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];




running = NO;
count = 0;
watch.text = @"00:00.00";

start.layer.cornerRadius = 45;
reset.layer.cornerRadius = 45;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}







- (IBAction)startpressed:(id)sender {

    if (running == NO) {
        running = YES;
        [start setTitle:@"STOPP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       NSDate *watch = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(1273636800 / 1000.0)];

        if (myTimer == nil) {

            myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0055
                                                       target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                       userInfo: nil
                                                       repeats:YES];

        }


    } else {

        running = NO;
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;
        [start setTitle:@"START" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}

- (IBAction)resetpressed:(id)sender {
    running =NO;
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer =nil;
    [start setTitle:@"START" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    count = 0;
    watch.text = @"00:00.00";


}


- (void)updateTimer {
    count++;

    int min = floor(count/100/60);
    int sec = floor(count/100);
    int mSec = count % 100;


    if (sec >= 60) {
        sec = sec % 60;

    }

    watch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d.%02d", min,sec,mSec];  
}
@end
```

this is my ViewController.h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSTimer *myTimer;
    BOOL running;
    int count;
    double methodStart;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *watch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *start;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *reset;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eins;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *zwei;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *drei;


- (IBAction)startpressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)resetpressed:(id)sender;

- (void) updateTimer;

@end
```

Comment: what issue faced ?

Comment: If you'd like show the top 3 ranking in your app, make a NSMutableArray and add item(time laps) to the mutable array in every stop timer. And then show the first, second, and third record after sorting the array. That's all.

Comment: can you give me the code for that so I can copy it into my Code ?

Answer (score 1):

Create array for holding lap history in class interface/extension and initialise it.

```
self.lapHistory = [@[] mutableCopy];
```

Capture and sort every lap time when lap is reset/stopped

```
- (IBAction)resetpressed:(id)sender {
   [self.lapHistory addObject:@(count)];
   self.lapHistory = [self.lapHistory sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
}
```

Display sorted ranking from lapHistory

```
-(void)displayRanking{
  NSMutableString *rankingResult = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (NSNumber *lap in self.lapHistory) {
        [rankingResult appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld\n",[lap integerValue]]];
    }
  NSLog(@"Ranking result is %@", rankingResult);
}
```